# jQuery element initialize - how can i

Tags: jquery

I am using `$(el).tootltips();` and it is working fine but it doesn't effect on future objects. How can I initialized this effect for future objects too.

Comment: You have to call the same function again after adding dynamic elements

Comment: What plugin are you using? `jQueryUI`? `Bootstrap`?

Comment: @D4V1D I am using bootstrap.

Comment: @D4V1D, thanks. that solution is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways:

1. focus on the element and initialize it.
2. wrap it in a function and call it when you add your future objects.

### 1.

```
$('body').on('focus', '.classNameOfFutureObj', function(){
    $(this).tootltips();
});
```

### 2.

```
function makeTooltip($el){
  $el.tootltips();
}
// you can call this function when you append your object in dom.
makeTooltip($('.classNameOfFutureObj'))
```

Comment: I don't want to use focus event.

Comment: so may be you would like to use option 2.

Comment: Option 2 will not work on future objects.